# How do you pipe output to the end of a file? (Java, Terminal)

Tags: java, terminal, pipe

I currently type this in the command line:

```
javac *.java && java NeuralNetApp > xorMomentumTest.txt
```

This erases everything in *xorMomentumTest.txt* and then fills it with output from the program.

What I want it to do is add the output to the end of *xorMomentumTest.txt*, instead of replacing its contents, so that I can run the program many times and keep all the output.

Comment: You need to do command >> file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
javac *.java && java NeuralNetApp >> xorMomentumTest.txt
```

This is more of an Operating System question, than a Java question.  I'm assuming you have a unix or linux OS.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference to others: > means replace file, >> means append to file.